# best way to write a function to return an array of String with limited size (char *x[MAX] vs char **x)?

Tags: c

What is the best way to write a function to return an array of String.
I use the following function:

```
void getOperatorNames(char *names[]) {

    int i=0;

    for(; i<MAX_OPERATORS; i++) {
            names[i] = malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(names[i], op[i].fname);
    }
}
```

and call it :

```
    char *MenuItems[MAX_OPERATORS];
    getOperatorNames(MenuItems);
```

But when I use `MenuItems` in a function with argument char ** it rises an exception and I don't know what is the cause.

What is the difference between `char *x[]` and `char **x`? IMO they must be equal!!

EDITTED:

```
struct operator{
    int id;
    char fname[32];
    char ename[32];

};

struct operator op[MAX_OPERATORS];
```

the operators is filled by random text.

Comment: There is no difference for a parameter declaration. For example the function main may be declared like int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) or like int main( int argc, char **argv )

Comment: How do you determine "best"?

Comment: So `MAX_OPERATORS` has a value of 6 or less?

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `op`? (Struct?)

Comment: And your `char **` has at least space for 6 pointers?

Comment: please provide a [mre].

Comment: *best way* is probably to use a struct. And maybe avoiding a void return for a `getxxxx(...)` function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow when I call my function with `char **MenuItems` it rises and exception. Is it mandatory to change declaration?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie MAX is a `#define` and can be anything, in my case 6.

Comment: @majidhajibaba As you was said already you should provide a minimal program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Well, you might have changed it yourself for this post, but in the code you're using both `char *MenuItems[6];` and `MAX_OPERATORS`.

Comment: Why hard-code the value `6` and `64`? Please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Instead of `malloc(64 * sizeof(char))` do `malloc(strlen(op[i].fname) + 1)` (`sizeof(char)` is specified to *always* be `1`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's not my problem cause but is a nice comment. Thank you and I will change it in my code.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio The best means what do you do in your projects for returning an array of string with limited size array?

Comment: @majidhajibaba But that's opinion-based and a close reason.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pack the array and its size together in a super-struct, and avoid the nasty-sized  functions arguments:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_OPERATORS 666

struct operators {
        unsigned count;
        struct operator{
                int id;
                char fname[32];
                char ename[32];
                } ops[MAX_OPERATORS];
        } ;

struct operators * getops(void)
{
struct operators   *ret;
unsigned uu;

ret = malloc (sizeof *ret);
if (!ret) return ret;
ret->count = MAX_OPERATORS;

for(uu=0; uu < ret->count; uu++) {
        ret->ops[uu].id= uu;
        sprintf(ret->ops[uu].fname, "f%2u", uu);
        sprintf(ret->ops[uu].ename, "e%2u", uu);
        }
return ret;
}
```

---

This is only the beginning, you can lateron make the array variable-sized (using malloc, or a VLA), but the interface would stay the same, and the caller would not need to know the value of `MAX_OPERATORS`, it only needs the `->count` structure element. You could also reuse it for other tables, using different counts.

Comment: Thank you @wildplasser. I will use your method in another section of my own code, but I wanna to return an array of `char *` to pass it to another function which gives `char **`.

Comment: You could pack an array of char* in a similar way.